# How to transform this function component into a class component? (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, constructor, components

I am new to React and struggle to transform this function component into a class component with a constructor(). I can't figure out how to transform the functions happening onSubmit and onClick.

Thank you very much.

**The function component:**

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './Options.css';

const Test = (props) => {
  const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);
  const [link, setLink] = useState('');

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newLink = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      text: link,
    };
    setLinks([...links].concat(newLink));
    setLink('');
  }

  function deleteLink(id) {
    const updatedLinks = [...links].filter((link) => link.id !== id);
    setLinks(updatedLinks);
  }

  return (
    <div className="OptionsContainer">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setLink(e.target.value)}
          value={link}
        />
        <button type="submit"> + </button>
      </form>
      {links.map((link) => (
        <div key={link.id}>
          <div>{link.text}</div>
          <button onClick={() => deleteLink(link.id)}>Remove</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we work with class components a couple of things got changed, we have a new object `this.state`, a new function `this.setState`, you have to bind your functions on the constructor if you want to have access to `this` inside it. I think you'll learn way more if you read the code, so here this is your component as a class component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './Options.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      links: [],
      link: '',
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newLink = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      text: this.state.link,
    };
    
    this.setState({links: [...this.state.links, newLink], link: ''});
  }

  deleteLink(id) {
    const updatedLinks = [...this.state.links].filter((link) => link.id !== id);
    this.setState({...this.state, links: updatedLinks });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div className="OptionsContainer">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ ...this.state, link: e.target.value})}
            value={this.state.link}
          />
          <button type="submit"> + </button>
        </form>
        {this.state.links.map((link, index) => (
          <div key={link.id}>
            <span>{link.text}</span>
            <button onClick={() => this.deleteLink(link.id)}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your original functional component, it's going to be hard to tell you what the class component should look like.

To answer your question about why `onSubmit` might not be working, it's because `onSubmit` is expecting to be passed an uncalled function, so that the `<form>` element can call that function itself when the time is right.

You are currently calling the function `this.handleOnSubmit()`, which returns nothing, so no handler for the form submit is properly assigned.  Try removing the call to the function, like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

Comment: You are also more than likely going to need to use `this.setState(...)`, which would replace in a way your `setLink` and `setLinks` function calls.  I recommend reading up on how to set state in a class component here - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I changed the component now to the original functional component.